# Nodejs, How to copy several file in nodejs without crash

Tags: node.js, http, stream, file-copying

I tried to copy several file with node js.

Here is my an example of what i'm trying to do :

```
var request = require('request');
 va photos [{ 'url': 'http://xxxx.com/im1', 'name' : 'name1' }, { 'url': 'http://xxxx.com/im12', 'name' : 'name2'    }, 
 for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
                        request(photos[i].source).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(photos[i].name));
  }
```

After maybe 1000 call i have a socket hang out error.

Following @Timothy Strimple advice i decided to use async module.

My code is now something like this :

```
async.whilst(function () { return !stop; },
                function (callback) {
                    console.log("get next 20 image");
                    JM.api('/' + album.id + '/photos', { after: next }, function (resf) {
                        if (!resf || resf.error) {
                            console.log(!resf ? 'error occurred' : resf.error);
                        }
                        console.log("albums" + album.id + " " + resf.data.length + " dir" + dir);

                        async.eachSeries(resf.data, function (photo, done) {

                            request(photo.source).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dir + "/" +photo.name));
                            console.log("copy of image " + img_basename);
                        }, function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('An images failed to copy');
                            } else {
                                console.log('All 20 image have been copied successfully');
                            }
                            if (resf.paging && resf.paging.cursors) {
                                console.log("suite de l'album à venir");
                                next = resf.paging.cursors.after;
                                setTimeout(function () { callback(); }, 5000);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("Fin de l'album");
                                stop = true;
                                setTimeout(function () { callback(); }, 5000);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('An images failed to process');
                        albumcallback();
                    } else {
                        console.log('All images in this group have been processed successfully');
                        albumcallback();
                    }
                }
            );// end while
```

I still having a crash after maybe 1 00 file copied. I'm sure that  async.whilst and async.eachSeries are weel because my log show that each call is on series. But i have a crash. I temporary solved the proble by ading a wait after each copy like this :

```
request(photo.source).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dir + "/" + img_basename));
                            console.log("copy of image " + img_basename);
                            setTimeout(function () { done(); }, 5000);
```

Is it a limit of request module ? How to change this fea line to make sure that each connection are closed before continung the program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request call and pipe call are asyncrhon. So i have to rewrite this line : request(photos[i].source).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(photos[i].name));

See here : 
[Downloading N number of remote files using Node.js synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629610/downloading-n-number-of-remote-files-using-node-js-synchronously)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to move to an asynchronous loop. Something like [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) from the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module would probably be ideal.

```
async.eachLimit(photos, 10, function(photo, done) {
    var r = request(photos[i].source).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(photos[i].name));
    r.on('finish', done);
}, function(err) {
    // All images done or there was an error
});
```

Now it will process all the items in your photos list, but it will only process 10 of them concurrently. This will prevent it from spinning up hundreds or thousands of concurrent outgoing connections.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your anwser. I need one more information because my code is a little more complicated. I can't get all my photos in one call, so i'm already in a kind of loop and i get my photos 20 by 20. So if i call asyn.eachlimit several times, it's going to make the job ? Or it's not going to serialize the call ? In advance thanks.

Comment: I recommend eachLimit if you're going to be passing in hundreds of things to be handled and you want to limit the rate at which they are processed. It would essentially replace what you've tried to do by breaking them into groups of photos. If you want to keep your group setup, you could use eachSeries in the outer loop. That would mean it only processes the second group of pictures after the first set has completed. https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries

Comment: I can't do that, because, for getting my photolist i'm doing something like : http.get('www.xxx.com'/path) and the path for getting my next 20 photos is in the response of my previous call. So i don't have a list to pass to eachserises. Maybe with until and a global variable for the url ?

Comment: Async seems to be the good anwser. I will have a look to the library and change my code.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunatly it's not solving my problem. I solve temporary the problems by doing a wait after each request(photo).pipe. The async library help to simplify my code.

Comment: How many concurrent photo requests are you making? Create a counter, and each time you start a photo request add one and write the value to console.log. When a request completes, subtract one and write the value to console.log. When the app crashes, see if there is a certain number of concurrent requests it crashes at. I still believe you're opening too many pipes for the settings on the machine it's running on.

Comment: Hi. I try what you said. I have only one concurent access withi this :    photocopier++;
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dir + "/" + name));
    //console.log("copy of image " + name);
    console.log("photocopier" + photocopier);
    copyconcurenceacces--;  I suspected that request or pipe is not syncrhone.